# Perl: Navigate a website, fill up form and launch browser (without submitting)

Tags: perl

I am looking for perl code to go to a website, navigate through a couple of links, fill up a form and then submit it. However, I want to launch the page with the filled up form in IE so that I can see exactly what's being submitted (and do a sanity check, perhaps change a couple of words) before actually submitting it.

I realize mechanize can be used to create the form and submit it automatically - but I'm stuck on how to "launch the filled up form webpage in a browser" part. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `Win32::OLE` to launch IE: [Controlling Internet Explorer Using Win32::OLE](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/controlling-internet-explorer-using-win3/184416120).

`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` should be able to do that in Firefox, but you'll need to install `mozrepl` extension.

Comment: Thanks Bohdan.This does the trick. I was looking to drive IE and WIN32::OLE is great.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

- [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aSimple)
- [HTTP::Request](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aRequest)
- [HTTP::Request::Form](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aRequest%3a%3aForm)
- [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder)
- [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize)
- [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox)
- [WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Scripter-0.029/lib/WWW/Scripter.pod)